# C# How to automatically include all .cs files in a folder for compiling?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4, csproj

I have a project containing a T4 template file which generates several .cs files based on the output (dll) of another project, which means the count & name of generated .cs files are varying. Now I want to:

1. Run T4 template to generate .cs files before build.
2. Include .cs files generated on point 1 in build.

Point 1 is archived by a before-build target. For point 2, I tried to use a wildcard to include all .cs files in the folder like that: `<Compile Include="GeneratedCode\*.cs" />`, but the problem is:

1. Any new generated .cs files are not included in the output dll for the first build, but are included for the second build.
2. VS doesn't refresh the project to show the new generated .cs files or to delete non-existing .cs files.
3. When I delete or add a .cs file under the folder in VS, VS replaces the wildcard with separated including command like `<Compile Include="GeneratedCode\A.cs" />`.

So what's the right way to include all .cs files in a folder for compiling to solve at least problem 1 & 3?

**++ BeforeBuild target content**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <_CommonProgramFiles>$([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('CommonProgramFiles(x86)'))</_CommonProgramFiles>
    <_CommonProgramFiles Condition=" '$(_CommonProgramFiles)' == '' ">$(CommonProgramFiles)</_CommonProgramFiles>       
    <TextTransformPath Condition="'$(TextTransformPath)' == ''">$(_CommonProgramFiles)\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\$(VisualStudioVersion)\TextTransform.exe</TextTransformPath>
    <!-- Initial default value -->
    <_TransformExe>$(TextTransformPath)</_TransformExe>
    <_TransformExe Condition="!Exists('$(_TransformExe)')">$(_CommonProgramFiles)\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\10.0\TextTransform.exe</_TransformExe>
    <_TransformExe Condition="!Exists('$(_TransformExe)')">$(_CommonProgramFiles)\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\11.0\TextTransform.exe</_TransformExe>
    <_TransformExe Condition="!Exists('$(_TransformExe)')">$(_CommonProgramFiles)\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\12.0\TextTransform.exe</_TransformExe>
    <_TransformExe Condition="!Exists('$(_TransformExe)')">$(_CommonProgramFiles)\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\13.0\TextTransform.exe</_TransformExe>
    <_TransformExe Condition="!Exists('$(_TransformExe)')">$(_CommonProgramFiles)\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\14.0\TextTransform.exe</_TransformExe>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="TransformOnBuild" AfterTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Error Text="Failed to find TextTransform.exe tool at '$(_TransformExe)." Condition="!Exists('$(_TransformExe)')"/>

    <ItemGroup>
        <_TextTransform Include="@(None)" Condition="'%(None.Generator)' == 'TextTemplatingFileGenerator'" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <!-- Perform task batching for each file -->
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(_TransformExe)&quot; &quot;%(_TextTransform.FullPath)&quot;"
        Condition="'%(_TextTransform.Identity)' != ''" 
        ContinueOnError="ErrorAndContinue" />
</Target>
```

Comment: You want an assembly to dynamically add source-code to itself? Sounds really strange to me. I think you should create a generator-assembly containing your t4-template that generates the source-code. Afterwards create your actual project from the created sources.

Comment: hm.. I think that EntityFramework T4 templates that generate POCO use the one-class-one-file-per-table approach, and that should be exactly the same as your case - pretty much indeterminate amount of .cs files, each one of pretty much indeterminate name, all finally get added to the project and are built together. You can peek the templates in EF6 and see how they do it. I think they are open-source, but if not, you should be able to get them from EF6 Nuget or VSIX files.

Comment: correction: in EF6 the templates are run as a manual step, on user's discretion, so that;s not automated pre-build step. But, it should be irrelevant if you don't care about intellisense.

Comment: @Suneet do you have an example of the target you're using for the transformation? are you integrating with some default transformation targets? also, which version of VS are you using? (2017 has a new opt-in project model that handles file globbing better which is active for .net core projects)

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm not trying to add source-code to an existing assembly. Those source-code files are generated before the assembly is built by a 'BeforeBuild' target task. The problem is even those files are generated before build, the final assembly doesn't contain them.

Comment: @MartinUllrich I'm using the target retrieved from 'Clarius.TransformOnBuild'. Added its content in question description.